# How do I switch to the new Steam version of Company of Heroes without downloading the entire game again?

Tags: steam, company-of-heroes

I already have Company of Heroes on Steam. Since the game is [switching over to Steamworks](http://www.coh2.org/news/2035/servers-for-coh1-to-continue-on-steamworks) for its multiplayer component sometime in May, a "New Steam Version" of the game has appeared beside the original.

[image]

Unfortunately when I try to install it Steam appears to require me to reinstall the game

[image]

Is there any way I can avoid having to download 9GB of game data all over again?

Comment: You can try this: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/56313/steam-download-skip-most-of-the-content/56335#56335 no guarantees though.

Answer (score 1):

Start downloading the new game until the folder structure got created, then stop Steam. Now simply copy the game folder to the new location. Start Steam again and it will download everything that does not match.

I'm not aware of any other way, so if this does not work you'll probably be left with no choice other than to download it again.

Note that Steam at times acts intelligently and uses identical existing files from other games, though that is very rarely the case and, judging from your question, not the case here.

Comment: That doesn't work because when I start downloading the new Steam version, the new game folder isn't created. I can create it manually ("Company of Heroes Relaunch"), but after copying Steam doesn't recognise the files and proceeds to continue downloading everything

Comment: You could try the same trick again (pause the current download/update, copying the files) and then go to the game's properties in Steam,  go to the 'Local files' tab and click 'Verify integrity of game cache'. Then it should only download the files that Steam considers 'damaged'.

Comment: @Terr That doesn't work either. The integrity check is completed almost immediately, with Steam reporting no errors, and the update progress does not change either.

Comment: @YiJiang'sEvilClone Then you simply can't avoid downloading all 9GB. The versions are probably simply too different, and/or have a different folder structure.

Answer (score 0):

Make a new folder called 'company of heroes relaunch' in the steam apps/common folder, then drag your old company of heroes files into it, then install the game in steam and it will discover the files it needs. I'm fairly sure this would work.